# Saving views after applying filter to column

Tags: list, list-view, filter, view, sharepoint-views

I am attempting to create filtered views to share with pertinent staff. I imported an Excel data sheet to create my list. And, up until now I have been able to achieve my desired end.

Until filtering to the program office shown in the screen shot below. I applied the filter, clicked "Save this View," gave it a name, and when i clicked save the data in the columns disappeared. This has happened for two other program offices. Why is this happening?

[image: Filtered view of the Program Office column]

[image: After saving, data in columns disappears]

Answer (score 0):

If you filter any column on the list view page it will be just a **temporary filter**.

In order to create a **Permanent filter**, you need to **Create a new view** and add **Filter** from **View settings**.

> **Filter**:
>
> Configure a view to display a subset of the items in a list by filtering them with information in columns of the list. For example, a view can show the items in a list that are for a specific project.

Check below official documentation by Microsoft for the same:

1. [Create, change, or delete a view of a list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9)
2. [Edit a list view in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edit-a-list-view-in-sharepoint-online-15916903-e79a-423f-b4e2-02d37e1ff372).

Comment: A-ha. That makes sense. Thank you for the reply!!

Comment: Welcome. As this answer helped you please upvote (  ^ ) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).